# Cross site scripting vulnerability issue for Richtext field

Tags: lotus-notes

We are using Lotus Notes technology for web application development. In order to make our application more secured, we are trying to fix some security level issues. One such issue that we are trying to fix is : Cross Site Scripting.

Here are the issue details. As part of application functionality data is getting processing from one web page to other web page to full fill the workflow process. During the process of data we require help to handle richtext fields data form special characters () to provide the security for hacking at third party level becuse our application is public domain.

Cross Site Scripting vulnerability is one that enables a hacker to place client side scripts (usually JavaScript) into web pages. XSS vulnerabilities generally occur when an application takes user input and outputs it in a page without validating, encoding or escaping it.

We are trying to solve the above issue for CKeditor (Third party tool) being used in our application. The CKeditor contains Richtext field data. We are unable to handle the request from backend to prevent the hacker from altering the request parameters.

For your kind information, We are using the domino Release 9.0.1 FP4 on windows/Longhom 6.2 intel and the version of CKeditor is 4.4.6. We searched online for various solutions for handling xss for rich text field(ck Editor) but could not find any. We also saw that CK Editor upgraded versions do not provide any fix for the XSS issue.

Kindly please provide a code level help to handle this issue to fix the XSS vulnerability?

Answer (score 2):

Look at Content Filtering (ACF):

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_acf.html

Comment: This might also be of interest https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/user/wpd_forms_xpages_security.html

Comment: The Content filtering(ACF)are already available in CKEditor and called the same functionality into Lotusnotes. but nowhere helpful to fixing our issue. Could you please provide your suggestions to proceed further on this?